# DefaultMessageListenerContainer's "isActive" vs "isRunning"

Tags: spring, message-queue, lifecycle, spring-jms

As said in the tittle, I need to know what is the main difference between those two `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` methods :

In the official documentation we have :

- [`public final boolean isActive()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractJmsListeningContainer.html#isActive) : Return whether this container is currently active, that is, whether it has been set up but not shut down yet.
- [`public final boolean isRunning()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractJmsListeningContainer.html#isRunning--) : Determine whether this container is currently running, that is, whether it has been started and not stopped yet.

This is quite subtil, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`active` simply means the container is "ready" to be started see `initialize()` - it is called from `afterPropertiesSet()`; it is reset when the container is `destroy()`ed.

`running` means it's been `start()` ed - and will actually consume messages.

Comment: If I want to turn off listner, what is better. set only  running to false or set both active and running to false.

Comment: `start()/stop()` set/reset `running`; `initialize()/shutDown()` set/reset `active`. It depends on what your requirements are. `stop()` just stops the consumers from getting new messages, but the consumers still exist. `shutDown()` closes the consumers. Most people call `stop + shutdown` and then `initialize + start` to restart. But if you just want to stop consuming for a short time, `stop/start` is all you need.