# Not able to stop an IBM MQ JMS consumer in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am NOT able to stop an `JMS` consumer dynamically using a `Spring Boot` REST endpoint.
The number of consumers stays as is. No exceptions either.

```
IBM MQ Version: 9.2.0.5
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**JmsConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@Log4j2
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName("my-ibm-mq-host.com");
        try {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("my-channel");
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(1234);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("my-QM");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while creating JMS connecion...", e.getMessage());
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }
}
```

**JmsListenerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class JmsListenerConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private JmsConfig jmsConfig;
    private Map<String, String> queueMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory mqJmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConfig.mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setConcurrency("5");
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        queueMap.put("my-queue-101", "101");
        log.info("queueMap: " + queueMap);

        queueMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
            endpoint.setDestination(e.getKey());
            endpoint.setId(e.getValue());
            try {
                log.info("Reading message....");
                endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> {
                    try {
                        log.info("Receieved ID: {} Destination {}", message.getJMSMessageID(), message.getJMSDestination());
                    } catch (JMSException ex) {
                        log.error("Exception while reading message - " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                registrar.setContainerFactory(mqJmsListenerContainerFactory());
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                log.error("Exception while reading message - " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
        });
    }
}
```

**JmsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jms")
@Log4j2
public class JmsController {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/stop", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String haltJmsListener() {
        JmsListenerEndpointRegistry listenerEndpointRegistry = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);

        Set<String> containerIds =  listenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainerIds();
        log.info("containerIds: " + containerIds);

        //stops all consumers
        listenerEndpointRegistry.stop(); //DOESN'T WORK :(

        //stops a consumer by id, used when there are multiple consumers and want to stop them individually
        //listenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("101").stop(); //DOESN'T WORK EITHER :(

        return "Jms Listener stopped";
    }
}
```

Here is the result that I noticed.

1. Initial # of consumers: 0 (as expected)
2. After server startup and queue connection, total # of consumers: 1 (as expected)
3. After hitting `http://localhost:8080/jms/stop` endpoint, total # of consumers: 1 (NOT as expected, should go back to 0)

Am I missing any configuration ?

Comment: Does the output from `log.info("containerIds: " + containerIds);` match `"101"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also call `shutDown` on the container; see my comment on this answer [DefaultMessageListenerContainer's "isActive" vs "isRunning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203368/defaultmessagelistenercontainers-isactive-vs-isrunning/43207064#43207064)

> `start()/stop()` set/reset `running`; `initialize()/shutDown()` set/reset `active`. It depends on what your requirements are. `stop()` just stops the consumers from getting new messages, but the consumers still exist. `shutDown()` closes the consumers. Most people call `stop + shutdown` and then `initialize + start` to restart. But if you just want to stop consuming for a short time, stop/start is all you need.

You will need to iterate over the containers and cast them to call `shutDown()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, how do I call the `shutDown()` method from `listenerEndpointRegistry` ? Not sure what to cast to.

Comment: Got it, never mind. `DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) listenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(containerId);
            dmlc.shutdown();`