# JMS MessageListenerContainer.stop() called but subscriber count doesn't decrease

Tags: java, spring-jms

I have a Spring Boot app which needs to dynamically subscribe and unsubscribe (non-durable) to a JMS topic. The subscription all works and so does the unsubscribe (according to the code) but the subscriber count on the JMS topic doesn't decrease. What is it I'm missing/not understanding?

Here's some stripped down code:

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DataStreamController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pubsubNonDurableJmsListenerContainer")
    private DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory;
    @Autowired
    private JmsListenerEndpointRegistry jmsListenerEndpointRegistry;
    private DataStreamListener listener;
    private String customer;
    private final String uuidStream1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private final String uuidStream2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public DataStreamController(String customer, DataStreamListener listener) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        subscribeToTopics();
    }

    public void subscribeToTopics() {
        SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint stream1TopicEndpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
        stream1TopicEndpoint.setDestination("stream1." + customer);
        stream1TopicEndpoint.setId(uuidStream1);
        stream1TopicEndPoint.setMessageListener(message ->
            onStream1(message);

        SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint stream2TopicEndpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
        stream2TopicEndpoint.setDestination("stream2." + customer);
        stream2TopicEndpoint.setId(uuidStream2);
        stream2TopicEndPoint.setMessageListener(message ->
            onStream2(message);

        jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(stream1TopicEndpoint, listenerContainerFactory, true);
        jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(stream2TopicEndpoint, listenerContainerFactory, true);
    }

    public void onStream1(final Message message) {
        // do some stuff
        listener.onData(// json object);
    }

    public void onStream2(final Message message) {
        // do some stuff
        listener.onData(// json object);
    }

    public void close() {
        jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(uuidStream1).stop();
        jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(uuidStream2).stop();
        logger.info("stream1 isRunning? " + jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(uuidStream1).isRunning());
        logger.info("stream2 isRunning? " + jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(uuidStream2).isRunning());
    }
}
```

When calling `close()` my logs say: `stream1 isRunning? false` and yet (as stated earlier) the subscriber is still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopping the container just stops the container from listening, it does not close the consumer. You need to call `shutDown()` to close the consumer.

[Not able to stop an IBM MQ JMS consumer in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725269/not-able-to-stop-an-ibm-mq-jms-consumer-in-spring-boot/73731402#73731402)